# Adding extra wrapper DIV to center content does not work in web browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have been playing around with Mathew James Taylor's three column liquid layout which you can see [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm). He gives additional code to reduce the display size and center it which is [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-convert-a-liquid-layout-to-fixed-width).

```
<div id="fixed"><!-- existing liquid layout here --></div>
```

And for the CSS

```
body {
text-align:center;
}
#fixed 
{
margin:0 auto;
width:90%;   /* you can use px, em or % */
text-align:left;
}
```

The problem I am having is this does not work in any broswer on my computer. Not in Chrome, Firefox, or Internet Explorer. However, when I loaded the same code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a35oqn0c/) it worked. What is wrong that it will not work on my computer in any browser? I have not seen this happen before.

By the way I know this can be done by changing the values in the body tag in CSS but Matthew's point was that his way of doing it in a container was better for older versions of internet explorer.

Comment: If it works in the JSFiddle but not standalone in your browser, it likely means that there is an issue in the way the HTML file is constructed.

Comment: If your `#fixed` element is always `90%` width than you could just use `position: absolute` and `left: 5%` to center it..

Comment: The article is already old. Modern browsers support flexbox already. That's a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tried flexbox and am going to move onto that and Bootstrap, but the above layout has been a good learning process for me. It seems like some people care about old versions of Internet Explorer because they have to, and some don't care. I take your point - old code.